# ng serve live reload doesn't work in script

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

When I just go with `ng serve` it detects my changes and reloads the page.
However, if I try using `npm run myStartScript` it does not.
myStartScript:

```
ng serve --deploy-url https://localhost:4200/ --ssl true --ssl-key \"my_store.key\"  --ssl-cert \"my_key_store.crt\"
```

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.4
```

Edit:
I did some more tests. Pointing my browser directly at `localhost:4200` works regardless of which `ng serve` command I use. But when I launch my project on a remote server (where the scripts are being pulled from `localhost`) it doesn't automatically reload.
In a previous project using the exact same configuration this worked. The only difference is the Angular version (4 vs. 6) and the Angular CLI version (1.0 vs. 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while, but I found the problem.
In an unrelated issue, I was getting a 404 from `sockjs-node`.
The fix is as presented here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8487#issuecomment-344665930

So apparently the WDS was choking on the error and refused to acknowledge requests to refresh the page. Resolving the sockjs-node error fixed my problem.